# Preimage of the set of critical value of an analytic function between smooth manifolds

Tags: manifolds, lebesgue-measure, analyticity, smooth-manifolds

I have some problems with the following exercise, maybe due to alack of knowledge:

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold and let $$ f \colon M \to N$$ be an analytic map. Denote by $C_f \subset M$ the set of critical points of $f$. How can I prove that if $C_f\neq M$, then $f^{-1}(f(C_f))$ is a null set?

I tried to find relations between some topological aspect of a null set but without any results. By Sard's Theorem $f(C_f)$ is a null set, and it seems reasonable that I have to use the fact that I have to extend my analytic function in order to solve the problem. But in general I don't know how to proceed. Keep in mind that my knowledge in measure theory is very limited :(

Using the analyticity of the $f$ I was able to prove that $f(C_f)$ is at most countable, but I don't know how to translate it to

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $M$ and $N$ need to be analytic manifolds, for merely smooth manifolds, the notion of an analytic map is not defined.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I did not know that. This was an exercise for the third week of course in global analysis, so my knowledge are pretty limited! Obviously your observation makes sense! Have you got some advice on how to proceed in solving this problem?

Comment: Since $f(C_f)$ is at most countable, it would suffice if you can show that $f^{-1}(p)$ is a null set for every $p\in N$ if $f$ is a non-constant analytic function and $M$ is connected.